# Do BA have bassinet seats in Premium Economy?

Tags: british-airways

Surprisingly hard to find the answer to this on their site pre-booking.

We're looking at taking a flight from London to SF and are considering premium economy — are bassinet seats available in that cabin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all BA World Traveller Plus (their name for premium economy) seat maps on [this page](https://www.britishairways.com/en-fr/information/seating/seat-maps/world-traveller-plus-seatmap).

They all show bassinets on the first row, on all aircraft.